# JAVA - How to avoid duplication of values in MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, duplicates

I'm new in MySQL. I have a problem here. I have a query of inserting a data to the database but my problem is how to avoid duplication of records.

So here are my codes:

```
private void btnSaveGuestActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

    String name = nameTextField.getText();
    String address = addressTextField.getText();
    String nationality = nationalityTextField.getText();
    String com = comNameTextField.getText();
    String email = emailTextField.getText();
    String contact = contactNoTextField.getText();

    if( name.isEmpty() || address .isEmpty() ||  nationality.isEmpty() || com.isEmpty() ||  email.isEmpty() ||  contact.isEmpty() ){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please input any of the following.");
    }
    else{
        try{
            String query = "INSERT INTO guestlist (Name, address, Nationality, CompanyName, email, contactNo)"
                         + "VALUES ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?";
    PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM guestlist");

    pst.setString(1, nameTextField.getText());
            pst.setString(2, addressTextField.getText());
            pst.setString(3, nationalityTextField.getText());
    pst.setString(4, comNameTextField.getText());
    pst.setString(5, emailTextField.getText());
    pst.setString(6, contactNoTextField.getText());

            pst.execute();


    pst.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }
    }
}
```

Sorry for my ignorance here but I'm very new to DBMS. I hope you would answer my question. Thanks a lot and have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 0):

In databases in general, you prevent duplication of records by creating unique indexes or constraints.  Actually, these are basically the same thing (unique constraints are implemented using unique indexes).

So, if you wanted `email` to be unique, you can do:

```
create unique index unq_guestlist_email on guestlist(email);
```

Of course, you can specify multiple columns, so the *combination* of all the columns has to be unique.

Then, if you try to insert a record that is already there, the database will return an error.  (You can ignore this error in various ways.)

Comment: So which means, to avoid duplication, all I have to do is to change it into UNIQUE? (If I'm not mistaken.)

Comment: @jhenryj09 . . . I' not sure what "it" refers to, but a unique index or constraint puts the database in charge of maintaining uniqueness.

Comment: Do you have an example of those that you've mention? Can I have a copy of those if you don't mind? :)

Answer (score 0):

in mysql you can use unique constrainst (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp).

But, if also you want validate insert data without errors in java, when you insert registers you can validate the columns that are part of your unique value, not to be repeated.